# How to download all of three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've been following [this documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene) on three.js and downloaded the entire (or so I thought) library from [here](https://threejs.org/build/three.js).
But every now and then I run into these functionalities like [OrbitControl](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls) and [OBJLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/OBJLoader) and I can't seem to find it within the downloaded three.js library.
What is the problem? Are these just extensions to the main framework?
How do I go about downloading all of these functionalities as well?

Comment: The [installation documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation) provides an examples of how to load OrbitControl from npm and cdn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how we typically go on about downloading and integrating a package in a project. I recommend you check this guide: https://nodesource.com/blog/an-absolute-beginners-guide-to-using-npm/ (or any other package manager guide of your choice) and reference this documentation: https://docs.npmjs.com/